# Selecting Optimal batch size for model as well as tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Currently, I'm using [tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) to load about 280,000+ images with a batch size 128 and for the model, I am using a batch size of 1024.

However, I am getting "E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:954] model_pruner failed: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Graph does not contain terminal node AssignAddVariableOp.".

On doing a simple [google search](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34499#issuecomment-652316457),

I am assuming that "The Device" i.e. TPU might not able to handle the I/O operation and the fix should be reducing batch size.

However, I have tried setting the dataset's batch size 32, 64, 128, 256, 1024 and for the model batch size, 1024, 128, 32, but seem to get the same error.[So basically using a large batch size and reducing by halving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884034/22073105)

I did find this method to calculate, however I am not sure how to [calculate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654424/how-to-calculate-optimal-batch-size) the size of tensor from tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory.